# how can i tracking click in custom html template mailchimp?

Tags: html, email, templates, mailchimp

i create HTML email template for mailchimp.
but when i want see click track in report, see: "Sorry, we couldn't get the stats you were looking for."

i think when i use custom html template, we must use mailchimp tag for sum data:

*|UNSUB|*
*|FORWARD|*
*|ARCHIVE|*
*|UPDATE_PROFILE|*
*|EMAIL|*
*|LIST:ADDRESS|*
*|LIST:COMPANY|*
*|CURRENT_YEAR|*
*|DATE|*

but i dont know how can use *|URL:YOUR_MERGE|* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it !
you dont need add any tag !
just type full address in your template:

```
<a href="http://yourlink.com" target="_blank"> yourlink!  </a>
```

your link must start with "http://", mailchimp change this link to