# How to track Mailchimp links from merge tags

Tags: mailchimp

I've just created a custom template to be used on Mailchimp.
Some links come from custom merge tags and point to the website related to Mailchimp. The problem is that those links from merge tags are not being tracked by Mailchimp.

I found this and of course tried but it didn't work:
[how can i tracking click in custom html template mailchimp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436098/how-can-i-tracking-click-in-custom-html-template-mailchimp)

As an example, one of my links looks like this:

```
<p mc:edit="product1_url">
    <a class="product-button" href="http://mywebsite.com*|PRODURL1|*" target="_blank">BUY NOW</a>
</p>
```

The PRODURL1 merge tag is type text and contains a path to a product, so the resulting url looks like http://mywebsite.com/product/123456 and it works if a click it on the sent email.

Any experience or direction?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after trying and trying and trying more I've found out why it wasn't working.

First part of the links MUST include the /, the second part (contained on the merge tag) MUST NOT include the /).

So now with this configuration Mailchimp tracks the links:

```
<a class="product-button" href="http://mywebsite.com/*|PRODURL1|*" target="_blank">BUY NOW</a>
```

Of course now PRODURL1 = "products/123456". So the same url is rendered, but this time tracked by Mailchimp.